# How do I find the natural domain for the following functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$H(x)= \frac{1}{x}$$

$$K(x)= \frac{1}{(x-4)(x-2)} $$

$$F(x)= \sqrt {x} $$

$$G(x)= \sqrt{ x-2} $$

Comment: For these types of questions, it is usually intended to be interpreted as the question "*Find the maximal subset of $\Bbb R$ which would be a valid domain for the function.*"  You should know that you are not allowed to divide by zero for a real function, and further you are not allowed to take the square root of a negative number for a real function (*note: these things may be allowed in more exotic contexts*).

Comment: I edited the question please use $\LaTeX$ for typing the mathematical expressions and please include your own thoughts in the question

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to find the *maximal* subset $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ s.t. with the given the algebraic expression for the specified function $f$, $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ with $x\mapsto f(x)$ is well defined.

In other words, you want to find the largest(*all points s.t. ...*) set $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ s.t. that you can evaluate the expression for all $x\in D$.

---

To give you some hints for your specified functions:

For $H,K$, the division is ill-defined if the denominator is $0$, thus you have to check for zeros in the expressions there.

For $F,G$, in the real case you can not take the square root of negative numbers, thus you ought to check for which points the expression under the root evaluates to a negative number.